# Is it possible to use F# record's labels as functions like in Haskell, or something similar?

Tags: haskell, f#, functional-programming, records

In Haskell, given this record:

```
data ARecord { labelA :: String, labelB :: Int }
```

we get this functions:

```
labelA :: ARecord -> String
labelB :: ARecord -> Int
```

F# doesn't seem to work this way. But, is there something similar?

**Edit**

By something similar I mean something that saves me from having to define the functions manually, as @kaefer suggested.

Comment: No, this is not possible in F# today. Adding support for this (not just for records, but for regular .NET types too) is *the* top F# [language feature request](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5663326-syntax-for-turning-properties-into-functions) at the moment.

Comment: @latkin that link is dead.  Did this feature request get added?

Answer (score 2):

It's easily defined.

```ml
type ARecord = { labelA : string; labelB : int }
let labelA { labelA = s } = s
// val labelA : ARecord -> string
```

**Edit**

The following function would compile to identical IL, with direct read access to the backing field, instead of the automatically generated instance property.
In contrast to normal experience with object-orientated *dot-notation*, it doesn't require type annotation to determine the record type.

```ml
let labelA' aRecord = aRecord.labelA
// val labelA' : aRecord:ARecord -> string
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. Having to define the function manually is precisely what I'm trying to avoid. I edited the question to be precise about this.

Comment: @LayGonzález I surmise the preferred way to access record fields in F# is via `record pattern` or property-like dot-notation.

Comment: I agree that it is very handy. Yet, couldn't we have both options? without defining manually the function, you could not do things like: `a |> labelA`